# Why is deadlock posssible here?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

I am currently learning about deadlocks in Go and when they can appear. I am viewing this code. I know a deadlock is possible here, but I cannot find it. Can someone please explain it to me?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reuters(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "REUTERS"
}
func bloomberg(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "BLOOMBERG"
}
func newsReader(reutersCh chan string, bloombergCh chan string) {
    ch := make(chan string, 5)
    go func() {
        ch <- (<-reutersCh)
    }()
    go func() {
        ch <- (<-bloombergCh)
    }()
    x := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("got news from %s \n", x)
}
func main() {
    reutersCh := make(chan string)
    bloombergCh := make(chan string)
    go reuters(reutersCh)
    go bloomberg(bloombergCh)
    newsReader(reutersCh, bloombergCh)
    newsReader(reutersCh, bloombergCh)
}
```

Comment: Both channel-sends, the one from `go reuters` and the one from `go bloomberg` will most probably be consumed by the first `newsReader` which means that the second `newsReader` will hang at the channel-receive operation `x := <-ch`.

Comment: what if we change the channel ch := make(chan string) to have no buffer. Is it still the same solution? @mkopriva

Comment: You still have the same problem because you have the `<-reutersCh` and `<-bloombergCh` channel-receive operations being potentially executed by the goroutines spawned by first `newReaders`.

Comment: I mean if it has no buffer, then can it consume both?

Comment: If you're looking for a solution then that would be [`select`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements).

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is how can the channel ch consume both <-reutersCh and <-bloombergCh if it has no buffer? Can you explain this to me?

Comment: See [send statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Send_statements): *"Both the channel and the value expression are evaluated before communication begins."* -- That means that `<-bloombergCh` (the value) in `ch <- (<-bloombergCh)` is evaluated **before** `ch` can begin receiving (the communication).

Comment: Aaaah, got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: Can you also show how select will solve this problem?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/yPJWCo7JYem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241542/discussion-between-stefan-hristov-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 2):

When you want to read from an empty channel, the channel blocks. After running:

```
go reuters(reutersCh)
go bloomberg(bloombergCh)
```

there will be one item in `reutersCh` and one item in `bloombergCh`. When you run

```
newsReader(reutersCh, bloombergCh)
```

you start two routines that read from both channels. It is very likely, that they finish before

```
newsReader(reutersCh, bloombergCh)
```

runs a second time. In this case, `reutersCh` and `bloombergCh` are empty, so der is no way you can read from them. When you can't read from these channels, you also can't write to the local channel `ch` in the `newsReader` function. When you can't write to the channel `ch` you can't read from the channel and therefore it blocks.

In conclusion, you write in `reutersCh` and `bloombergCh` once and try to read from them twice. Two routines will block for sure and when the two routines from the second call of `newsReader` block (which is very likely), your program will block completely.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks for the good explanation